# GoogleDrive api read write single file

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I looked on google's website and couldn't find how to do this. I want to be able read/write to a single file on my google drive to save user's account information (either to a txt file or sql). I found how to create a file and read, but I can't find anything like fs.readFile() and fs.writeFile(). Is this even possible, and how do I do this?

It's probably that I'm just stupid, but I can't find this anywhere.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not read from google drive, write the content to a file, change it and then reupload it?

```
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': 'your.file.txt'
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'text/plain',
  body: fs.createReadStream('files/your.file.txt')
};
drive.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }
});
```

See https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads (for uploading) and https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update (for updating)